# Passing Values from Lightning:menuitem

Tags: lightning-aura-components, button, table, lightning-buttonmenu

//Table with recordsetvar

```
<td data-label="EDIT AND DELETE">
   <lightning:buttonMenu alternativeText="More options"  onselect="{!c.editDeleteJS}" iconSize="small" aura:id="{!grpsegrel.Id}">
     <lightning:menuItem label="Edit"  value="editGrp" iconName="utility:edit"  />
     <lightning:menuItem label="Delete" value="deleteGrp"iconName="utility:delete" /> 
   </lightning:buttonMenu>
 </td>
```

//JSController Method

```
editDeleteJS: function(component, event, helper) {
    var menuValue = event.detail.menuItem.get("v.value");
    switch(menuValue) {
        case "editGrp": helper.doEdit(); break;
        case "deleteGrp": helper.doDelete(); break;
    }
}
```

//Helper

```
 doEdit: function(component, event, helper) {

    var editRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:editRecord");
    var a = editRecordEvent.getSource();
    var idb = a.getLocalId();
    alert(idb);
    editRecordEvent.setParams({
        //"recordId": event.target.id
        "recordId": idb
    });
    editRecordEvent.fire();

}
```

From helper I am trying to capture that id, but either event.target or .getsource() are not returning the id any idea what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<lightning:buttonMenu alternativeText="More options"  onselect="{!c.editDeleteGRP}" iconSize="small" class = "{!grpsegrel.Id}"/>
```

Added Class in the the button menu and in controller retrieved using this line of code:

`var tempid = event.getSource().get("v.class");`

Answer (score 0):

Documentation says this.

```
editRecord : function(component, event, helper) {
    var editRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:editRecord");
    editRecordEvent.setParams({
         "recordId": component.get("v.contact.Id")
   });
    editRecordEvent.fire();
}
```

You need to implement force:hasRecordId then you will get the record id automatically from the context variable.
Or 
You need to set an `<aura:attribute>` of object type and get the Id like  v.contact.Id. Hope this helps